# Group dictionary by multiple keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{
04-21: {
          a: [1,2,3,4]
          a: [5,6,7]
          b: [8,9]
       }
04-22: {
          a: [1,3,4]
          a: [2,6,7]
          a: [3,8]
          b: [1,4,2]
          b: [8,9]
       }
}
```

How do I group this dictionary by first and second value to produce:

```
{
 04-21:{
         a: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
         b: [8,9]
       }
 04-22:{
         a: [1,3,4,2,6,7,3,8]
         b: [1,4,2,8,9]
}
```

Following code gives me error:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(L, lambda x: x[0] ,x[1]): 
    print(key + " :", list(group))
```

Comment: Those dictionaries are illegal, keys must be unique

Comment: Also those keys are *subtractions*, involving octals (in Python 2) or a syntax error (Python 3). Could you give a [mre]?

Comment: I am unable to write the iterator. The first key is a folder with date as name

Comment: a and b are dictionaries in it self

Comment: Can you provide your actual code? We don't know what is `L` and the example you provided is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you execute that dictionary in Python i.e.:

```
d = {'04-21': {
          'a': [1,2,3,4],
          'a': [5,6,7],
          'b': [8,9]
       },
'04-22': {
          'a': [1,3,4],
          'a': [2,6,7],
          'a': [3,8],
          'b': [1,4,2],
          'b': [8,9]
       }
}
```

The dictionary becomes:

```
{'04-21': {'a': [5, 6, 7], 'b': [8, 9]}, '04-22': {'a': [3, 8], 'b': [8, 9]}}
```